# How could I keep Math.random() from returning a different value each time I call the variable it's stored under?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I have an assignment right now which requires that I use `Math.random()` stored in a variable which I have named `randomNumberBetween0and5` (It's actually `Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0);` which returns a number between 0 and 5. I use this number to refer to the index of some arrays elsewhere in the code.) I call it twice more later in my code, but I need `Math.random()` to execute only once then store its' value in the `randomNumberBetween0and5` variable for later use without changing if I call the variable two or three more times.

I've tried to store the value of `randomNumberBetween0and5` in another variable and (as expected) that didn't help the situation. Any help would definitely be appreciated! Thank you!

(Here's all of the code just in the case you'd like to see it.)

```
var names = ["Lázaro", "Aviram", "Samuel", "Miles", "Felix"]; // Defining an array of random names
var people = []; // Declaring the array to hold each instance of the 'Person' object

// For() to create one new instance thrice for three names of the 'names' array in the 'Person' object defined in 'person.js'

for (var i=0;i < 3;i++) {
    var randomNumberBetween0and5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0); // Randomly choosing a number for the arrays to be passed to the 'Person()' object's methods defined in 'person.js'
    var newInstance = new Person.generate(names.splice(randomNumberBetween0and5,randomNumberBetween0and5+1),Person.actions[randomNumberBetween0and5],Person.jobs[randomNumberBetween0and5],i+1); // Creating a new instance of the 'Person()' object and passing a random name, action (from the Person object's properties), and job (also from the Person object's properties), along with the current loop number for the row to use (i begins at 0 so it becomes 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2 when a 1 is added)
    //people.push(newInstance); // Adding the new instance to the 'people' array of instances
    people.push(newInstance); // Adding the newly created instance of 'Person' to the variable 'people'
}; // Ending the for()

console.log(people); // Logging the 'people' array for debugging
console.log("Main.js has been completely interpreted -- Nothing has broken yet."); // Reassuring console log to state that this file has completely executed without breaking
```

Comment: If you store the number in a variable it will stay setted and it will not change... that's the purpose of variables in programming languages: keep data. You're doing something else with that variable, otherwise it's impossible that it changes anyhow.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli `variable` and `keep data` in the same sentence doesn't fit. Maybe `constant` would be more appropriate but not quite correct.

Comment: `Math.random()` is in a variable. That means the variables' value changes each time it's called. I suppose a constant may not allow the value to change after `Math.random()` sets it, but I'm almost certain JavaScript doesn't have constants.

Comment: Your understanding of what happens with that variable when you use it is off. `Math.random()` is called when you create the variable, but never again. It is only called again because you have it in a loop

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this snippet explains it:

```
// When Math.floor is initially called it creates the random number
// store this in variable: randomNumberBetween0and5
var randomNumberBetween0and5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0); 

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // randomNumberBetween0and5 will never change in this function
   console.log(randomNumberBetween0and5);
}
```

Problem in your code is that you call Math.floor in the loop. this will always create a random.

Try this with your code:

```
var names = ["Lázaro", "Aviram", "Samuel", "Miles", "Felix"]; 
var people = []; 
var randomNumberBetween0and5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0); 

for (var i=0;i < 3;i++) {
  console.log('randomNumberBetween0and5 is: ' + randomNumberBetween0and5);
  var newInstance = new Person.generate(names.splice(randomNumberBetween0and5,randomNumberBetween0and5+1),Person.actions[randomNumberBetween0and5],Person.jobs[randomNumberBetween0and5],i+1); 
  people.push(newInstance); 
};
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my source but `randomNumberBetween0and5` _is_ changing during my `for()` loop.

Comment: but it is INSIDE the Loop. Move it outside.

Comment: I've moved it above (under my first two variable declarations) and it's still happening :(

Comment: Could you please post a simplified Version of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay if you make `randomNumberBetween0and5` an array so that it can store 3 different numbers at the same time?

```
var randomNumberBetween0and5 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    randomNumberBetween0and5.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*5));
    //do stuff with randomNumberBetween0and5[i]
}
```